# Hierarchical Data - option(maxrecursion 10) error

Tags: hierarchical

I have the below code where I get the msg:
*Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 10 has been exhausted before statement completion.*

There are possibly 10 levels in the dataset.

```
WITH Bom_hierarcy AS 
(

SELECT
BOMVERSION.ITEMID AS 'MainItem',
BOM.ITEMID,
BOM.BOMID,
BOM.DATAAREAID,
BOM.PARTITION,
1 AS 'Level'


FROM Ax2012R3prod.dbo.BOM
INNER JOIN BOMVERSION ON BOM.BOMID = BOMVERSION.BOMID and BOM.DATAAREAID = BOMVERSION.DATAAREAID and BOM.PARTITION = BOMVERSION.PARTITION

WHERE
BOMVERSION.ACTIVE = 1 and BOM.DATAAREAID IN ('sks')

UNION ALL

SELECT
BOMVERSION.ITEMID AS 'MainItem',
Bom_sub.ITEMID,
Bom_sub.BOMID,
Bom_sub.DATAAREAID,
Bom_sub.PARTITION,
Level +1 AS 'Level'

FROM Ax2012R3prod.dbo.BOM AS Bom_sub
INNER JOIN BOMVERSION ON Bom_sub.BOMID = BOMVERSION.BOMID and Bom_sub.DATAAREAID = BOMVERSION.DATAAREAID and Bom_sub.PARTITION = BOMVERSION.PARTITION
INNER JOIN Bom_hierarcy CTE ON Bom_sub.ITEMID = CTE.MainItem and Bom_sub.DATAAREAID = CTE.DATAAREAID and Bom_sub.PARTITION = CTE.PARTITION

WHERE
BOMVERSION.ACTIVE = 1 and Bom_sub.DATAAREAID IN ('sks')

)


SELECT
Bom_hierarcy.MainItem,
Bom_hierarcy.ITEMID,
Bom_hierarcy.Level,
Bom_hierarcy.BOMID,
Bom_hierarcy.DATAAREAID


FROM Bom_hierarcy
option (maxrecursion 10)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please edit your question and add more details or explanations to it. I can't understand what is your question.

Comment: @novonimo OP have a query that has more than 10 recursion calls which reached the limit of what the database can offer, thus seeking workarounds or ways to simplify the query.

Comment: that's a good one, please edit your question and add the above explanation into it. good luck :)